# Cannot connect to service through traefik ingress on k3s

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, k3s

Using default k3s installation with vcluster I want to expose my service of type clusterIP to the world with ingress.

`curl 172.18.62.21/some_endpoint`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /some_endpoint</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

`curl 10.42.0.39:8080`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello Kubernetes!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300" >
</head>
<body>

  <div class="main">
    <img src="/images/kubernetes.png"/>
    <div class="content">
      <div id="message">
  Hello world!
</div>
<div id="info">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>namespace:</th>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>pod:</th>
      <td>aida-temp-env-aida-api-deployment-c8092f93-f55885d6-zk9sk</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>node:</th>
      <td>- (Linux 5.15.0-60-generic)</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  paulbouwer/hello-kubernetes:1.10.1 (linux/amd64)
</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

`k describe ingress`:

```
Handling connection for 12042
Name:             aida-temp-env-ingress-c8343d74
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        default
Address:          172.18.62.21,172.18.62.22,172.18.62.23
Ingress Class:    traefik
Default backend:  aida-temp-env-aida-api-service-c86c8a2d:80 (10.42.0.39:8080)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *
              /some_endpoint   aida-temp-env-aida-api-service-c86c8a2d:80 (10.42.0.39:8080)
Annotations:  <none>
Events:       <none>
```

`yaml`:

```
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: aida-temp-env-dockerconfig-secret-c845f04c
immutable: false
stringData:
  .dockerconfigjson: *****
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: aida-temp-env-aida-api-deployment-c8092f93
spec:
  minReadySeconds: 0
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      cdk8s.io/metadata.addr: aida-temp-env-aida-api-deployment-c80a799a
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        cdk8s.io/metadata.addr: aida-temp-env-aida-api-deployment-c80a799a
    spec:
      automountServiceAccountToken: false
      containers:
        - image: paulbouwer/hello-kubernetes:1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: main
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1500m
              memory: 2048Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 1000m
              memory: 512Mi
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            privileged: false
            readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 2000
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: aida-temp-env-dockerconfig-secret-c845f04c
      restartPolicy: Always
      securityContext:
        fsGroupChangePolicy: Always
        runAsNonRoot: true
      setHostnameAsFQDN: false
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: aida-temp-env-aida-api-service-c86c8a2d
spec:
  externalIPs: []
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    cdk8s.io/metadata.addr: aida-temp-env-aida-api-deployment-c80a799a
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: aida-temp-env-ingress-c8343d74
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: aida-temp-env-aida-api-service-c86c8a2d
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: aida-temp-env-aida-api-service-c86c8a2d
                port:
                  number: 80
            path: /some_endpoint
            pathType: Prefix
```

Initially I wanted to expose the service using LoadBalancer servcie, but it's external ip would stay in pending state forever. I then added a MetalLB and it succesfully provided an external ip(I then got rid of it in favor of clipperlb)

EDIT:
I also did run the `k logs traefic` and the output is:

*level=error msg="Skipping service: no endpoints found" namespace=vcluster-aida-api-pr-112 serviceName=aida-temp-env-aida-api-service-c86c8a2d-x-default-x--bcdba98931 servicePort="&ServiceBackendPort{Name:,Number:80,}" providerName=kubernetes ingress=aida-temp-env-ingress-c8343d74-x-default-x-aida-api-pr-112*

I also did check `k get endpoints aida-temp-env-aida-api-service-c86c8a2d-x-default-x--bcdba98931 -n vcluster-aida-api-pr-112`, output:

*aida-temp-env-aida-api-service-c86c8a2d-x-default-x--bcdba98931   10.42.0.39:8080   6h5m*